# function in javascript is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, qunit

i have this js and qunit test below. why the browser gave me the listClasses is not defined? How to solve it. I saw mostly did

```
function ajax() {  
$.ajax({   
});}
```

but if i did like below how to do the test?

```
$('#MregisteredClasses').on('pageinit', function listClasses(){
var rowInput = "1";
var pageInput = "1";

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/getRegisteredClassesData.html',
    data: ( {rows : rowInput , page : pageInput}),
    type: 'POST',

    success: function(json_results){
    $('#list').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"</ul>');
        listItems = $('#list').find('ul');
        $.each(json_results.rows, function(key) {
            html = "<li data-mini='true' id='icon'><a href='http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/MRegisteredClassesDetail.phone?courseId=" 
                   + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] + "&regNo=" + [json_results.rows[key].regNo] +
                   "' rel='external'>" + json_results.rows[key].courseName+ "</a>"
                   + "<a href='http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/MRateCourse.phone?courseId=" 
                   + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] + "&regNo=" + [json_results.rows[key].regNo] + 
                   "' rel='external'>RATE THIS COURSE</a></li>" ; 
            listItems.append(html); 
        });

        $('#list ul').listview(); 
    },
});
});
```

and this is qunit test

```
 test('asynchronous test', function() {  
// Pause the test, and fail it if start() isn't called after one second  
stop();  

listClasses(function() {  
    // ...asynchronous assertions  
    ok(true, "Success"); 
});  

setTimeout(function() {  
    start();  
}, 2000);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#MregisteredClasses').on('pageinit', function listClasses(){ ...` is incorrect usage.

The function either needs to be anonymous (i.e. drop the `listClasses` bit) in which case running `listClasses()` will fail.

What you need to do is externalise the function declaration.

i.e.:

```
function listClasses(){
  var rowInput = "1";
  var pageInput = "1";

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/getRegisteredClassesData.html',
    data: ( {rows : rowInput , page : pageInput}),
    type: 'POST',

    success: function(json_results){
    $('#list').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"</ul>');
        listItems = $('#list').find('ul');
        $.each(json_results.rows, function(key) {
            html = "<li data-mini='true' id='icon'><a href='http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/MRegisteredClassesDetail.phone?courseId=" 
                   + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] + "&regNo=" + [json_results.rows[key].regNo] +
                   "' rel='external'>" + json_results.rows[key].courseName+ "</a>"
                   + "<a href='http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/MRateCourse.phone?courseId=" 
                   + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] + "&regNo=" + [json_results.rows[key].regNo] + 
                   "' rel='external'>RATE THIS COURSE</a></li>" ; 
            listItems.append(html); 
        });

        $('#list ul').listview(); 
    }
});
}
```

Then call the function from the `on` command:

```
$('#MregisteredClasses').on('pageinit', listClasses)
```

Assuming your script only failed on `listClasses()`, then I would assume that the `listClasses` name is just dropped silently.

Comment: Joe bowman : i try ur answer than it display this error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'
Source:  
http://137.57.102.146:8080/Training/js/MRegisteredClasses.js:23

Comment: As the error says, the object returned by `$('#list ul')` has no `listview()` function. Where is listview defined?

Comment: $('#list ul').listview(); is this not define the listview?

Comment: nope - that's calling the `listview()` function. The function must be defined elsewhere, in order to be called. Do you need to include another script file somewhere that includes the listview function?

Comment: i don't understand. the listview is the method for jquerymobile. am i right?

Comment: mostly from the forum, they just used the listview.. i didn't see they define it anywhere

Comment: i got it, need to include the jquerymobile.js.. but now, why the error said there's no assertion. but i already put ok(true, "Success"); inside the listClasses function

Answer (score 2):

There's [a difference](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl) between **function declaration** and **named function expression**.

The declaration is of the form:

```
function myFunc() {
    /* body */
}
```

Expressions are everything else:

```
var x = function myFunc() {
    /* body */
};

// or

alert(function myFunc() {
    / * body */
});
```

When a function expression has a name after the `function` keyword, the function is accessible by this name only inside the function body. Hence your problem.

```
var x = function myFunc() {
    /* body */
};

x(); // okay
myFunc(); // reference error
```

More info in [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).